# 'ld86: no start symbol' when I try to combine 2 object files

Tags: object, ubuntu, assembly, kernel, ld

so for a small project I have for my OS course, we're supposed to make a very small kernel. We're provided with a couple of assembly files and so on; essentially for this part we're supposed to use the following lines:

```
bcc -ansi -c -o kernel.o kernel.c
as86 kernel.asm -o kernel_asm.o
ld86 -o kernel -d kernel.o kernel_asm.o
dd if=kernel of=floppya.img bs=512 conv=notrunc seek=3
```

ld86, where it's supposed to link kernel.o and kernel_asm.o, is where it goes wrong. It issue the error in the title (ld86: no start symbol), and if I then try to use the dd utility, it tells me that it failed to open kernel (because the file was never created by ld86)

I've tried looking up the error for over an hour now, and I have found nothing. Any help (even speculation) would be appreciated.

Comment: If on the other hand the entry point for your code is in the _C_ file then you will need to have a function called `main` defined. If not, then you will get the same error.

Comment: This is really an ld86 limitation, since `-d` strips the header so there is no use for the entry point information anyway.

Comment: @Jester : That is true that `-d`will strip the headers, but LD86 still requires the label to exist although it is effectively useless. I left that part out to simplify my description.

Comment: Something you should be aware of @OmarA.Yousry is that because your ld86 command line lists `kernel.o` first before `kernel_asm.o`, you are required to put `main` in `kernel.c` when using the `-d` option with _LD86_ and creating the kernel. Because the kernel will be stripped with `-d` option and output to a flat binary make sure your function `main` is the **first** function that appears at the top of `kernel.c`. The linker will place the code in the binary in the order they are listed.The first instruction in the first file (`kernel.o` in your case) will be the first instruction of `kernel`